# Devexpress report label not showing value

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, reporting, devexpress-windows-ui

Can anyone tell me why same bounded xrLabel in details showing correct value but in page or report header label value is null.

If I set null text value on run time null text value is displayed in page header. In report detail value  is set to db value.

Happy to give more details if necessary.

Thanks

EDIT : code for opening print preview

```
    private void barItemPrint_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int _rId = ((Raspored)rasporedBindingSource.Current).Id;

            RasporedReport1 report = new RasporedReport1();

            report.DataSource = _context.RasporedStavke.Where(r => r.Id == _rId);

            ReportPrintTool printTool = new ReportPrintTool(report);
            printTool.ShowPreview(UserLookAndFeel.Default);

        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: We need the code you wrote so we can find out what you did wrong or missed.

Comment: I don't have any code. I'm using designer and only drag and drop label/field from Field List on the report